# ByteArray converted to InputStream and set to Imageview via BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null

Tags: android

I have a method that takes InputStream as an parameter ,for that I converted bytearray to inputstream and set this to imageview via BitmapFactory.decodeStream returns null ,that is ; the imageview doesn't shows any image ...If done via directly without converting to input stream it works

not working method

```
ImageView thumbContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                byte bitmapData[]=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO));   
                InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapData);
                Bitmap bit=BirthdayCalculation.ShrinkBitmap(is,200, 200);
                thumbContact.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

working method

```
ImageView thumbContact = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
                byte bitmapData[]=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO));                
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.length);
                thumbContact.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

updated code

```
public static  Bitmap ShrinkBitmap(InputStream is, int width, int height){

         BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null,bmpFactoryOptions);

            int heightRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outHeight/(float)height);
            int widthRatio = (int)Math.ceil(bmpFactoryOptions.outWidth/(float)width);

            if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1)
            {
             if (heightRatio > widthRatio)
             {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = heightRatio;
             } else {
              bmpFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = widthRatio; 
             }
            }

            bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null,bmpFactoryOptions);
         return bitmap;
        }
```

Comment: What is a code in your `ShrinkBitmap()` method?

Comment: I updated my code ,pls have a look